# stream video through multiple servers

Tags: php, video-streaming

I've got a peculiar problem.

Server **1A** is a server with witch the users interact. Servers **2B**, **2C** and **2D** store video content.

On a website, a html video tag is placed

```
<video src="server1adomain.com/videos?video=Gy12C899">
```

[image]

Whenever this content is fetched, a backend script on server 1A determines on which server (2B,2C or 2D) the video is stored and fetches it. Lets say it is on 2B. I do not want to wait for the whole video to be fetched from 2B and stored in 1A server, and only after all that time be send to the user. Instead, I'd like a continuous stream to be flowing from 2B to 1A and to the user simultaneously. That way the user gets the first frames of the video with minimal delay.

What is the standard solution for this problem? I've looked at src of videos on youtube, and they all seem to be fetched from the same domain, so this approach must be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions that are more or less industry standard. I would recommend against devising other hacky solutions to your problem.

First, big streaming sites use [Content Delivery Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDNs), where the actual content is hosted. These servers are different from the web servers (that host the web page or scripts) and operate independently; their main purpose is to host video content and store it closer to the user's location. Your web application's job would be to replace the video source link that points to server A with a *direct* link to the content server—whichever is closer to the user, or whichever is responding faster (a typical load-balancing case). In the case of your second-tier servers, you should set up a web server on them (like Nginx) and link to the videos directly.

Note that when you inspect your browser's network requests going to YouTube, they use different domains. The video content comes from a completely different source than the actual website—it's most likely a server near you with whom your ISP has a direct peering connection.

Make sure that your videos, if they are MP4 files, have their MOOV atom at the start of the file. This decreases startup delay, since the client may start playing even if the whole file is not transmitted yet. With ffmpeg, you can do this by adding the `-movflags +faststart` option while encoding (use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4` to just fix an existing file). Or use the `qt-faststart` program (or [some implementation](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart) of it) on an existing file.

The best option would be to pair the CDN approach with the use of [HTTP adaptive streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming) (DASH or HLS). Here, instead of a simple HTML5 video source that is most likely one big file, you would stream individual chunks of video. This leads to faster startup times and better handling of different client bandwidths. However, it's much more complicated to set up from scratch. There are, of course, vendors that offer DASH-type streaming solutions where you just have to give them the source video, and you can implement their player on your website. They'll take care of the encoding and CDN stuff. Some examples are Bitmovin, Encoding.com, or Wowza.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. CDN seems like the way to go in most cases. The reason why I'd like to stream through an intermittent server is to hide the locations of the storage servers. I found a Q&A that suggests a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417350/php-curl-realtime-proxy-stream-file#answer-38418060, but I was only able to directly download video file. When I tried setting `src` attribute in html video tag to the php script, I got a 400 error. Are you aware of any solution to this problem?

Comment: Ahh, the 400 error was my bad. It works now, but id does wait for the file to download. I'll inspect if this has to do with moov atom

Comment: yep, the code in q&a seems to work fine on my local computers.

Comment: Could be the moov atom, yes. If you really want to hide the location, the option to proxy through PHP could work, but you're funneling everything through one server, which is not ideal, performance-wise.